# DVBT Radio channels have no sound on vlc

Tags: sound, vlc, dvb-t

i play dvbt tv channels without any problem on vlc

but the radio channels have no sound

i did run vlc from terminal and got this error messages:

```
[h264 @ 0x7f04000f3f80] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7f04000f3f80] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7f04000f3f80] mmco: unref short failure
[00007f0404158938] ts demux: MPEG-4 descriptor not found for pid 0x3f3 type 0x11
[00007f0404158938] ts demux: MPEG-4 descriptor not found for pid 0x623 type 0x11
[00007f0404168738] packetizer_mpeg4audio packetizer: AAC channels: 1 samplerate: 24000
[00007f0404158938] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 8, expected 11) for PID 18
[00007f0404158938] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 9, expected 12) for PID 18
[00007f0404158938] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 15, expected 7) for PID 18
```

...

```
[00007f0404158938] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (misc PSI): Bad CRC_32 table 0x50 !!!
```

please help me

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

today,i upgrade the linux kernel to 4.2.0.19 
and 
vlc plays radio without any problem